# Table with two different variables starting at the same time

Tags: data, list-manipulation

I have the following code:

`Table[{a, b}, {a, 0, 2}, {b, 10, 12}]`

which gives me the following output:

`{{{0, 10}, {0, 11}, {0, 12}}, {{1, 10}, {1, 11}, {1, 12}}, {{2,  10}, {2, 11}, {2, 12}}}`

What I want is by using `Table` to generate an output where value of `a` and `b` start at the same time such as to get `{{first value of a,first value of b},{second value of a,second value of b},{third value of a,third value of b}}`. In the example above, the output would be then:

`{{0,10},{1,11},{2,12}}`

How can I do this using `Table`?

Comment: Does it have to be `Table`? This is more readable in my opinion: `MapThread[List, {Range[0, 2], Range[10, 12]}]`

Comment: @MarcoB thanks! I think this is very useful as well to me!. Originally, I thought I could only do my code with `Table` but your suggestion also works for me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
list=Table[{a, b}, {a, 0, 2}, {b, 10, 12}];
Diagonal[list]
```

Or

```
list=Table[{a, b}, {a, 0, 2}, {b, 10, 12}];
Table[list[[i, i]], {i, Length@list}]
```

Comment: `list=Table[{a, b}, {a, 0, 2}, {b, 10, 12}];Table[list[[i, i]], {i, Length@list}]`

Comment: Thank you so much !

Answer (score 6):

For compatible lists of iterators:

```
{a0, a1} = {0, 2};
{b0, b1} = {10, 12};

Table[{a, b0 + a}, {a, a0, a1}]

Transpose[{Range[a0, a1], Range[b0, b1]}]

Thread[{Range[a0, a1], Range[b0, b1]}]

Inner[List, Range[a0, a1], Range[b0, b1], List]

{0, b0} + # & /@ Range[a0, a1]
```

all give

> ```
>  {{0, 10}, {1, 11}, {2, 12}}
> ```

Comment: Thank you so much kglr! This is great !