# Looping with "Table" abreast over more than two variables

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

```
Clear["Global`*"]
S1 = Inverse[{{0.5, 0}, {0, 0.2}}];
R1 = RotationMatrix[Pi/3];
p1 = {1, 1};

S2 = Inverse[{{1, 0}, {0, 0.5}}];
R2 = RotationMatrix[Pi/6];
p2 = {2, 2};

H1 = R1 . Transpose[S1] . S1 . Transpose[R1];
J1 = -(H1 . p1 + Transpose[H1] . p1);
C1 = p1 . H1 . p1 - 1;

H2 = R2 . Transpose[S2] . S2 . Transpose[R2];
J2 = -(H2 . p2 + Transpose[H2] . p2);
C2 = p2 . H2 . p2 - 1;

Show[Table[Graphics[{Red, Point[p]}], {p, {p1, p2}}],
 Table[ContourPlot[{x, y} . H . {x, y} + Transpose[J] . {x, y} + C == 
    0, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}], {H, {H1, H2}}, {J, {J1, J2}}, {C, {C1,
     C2}}], Axes -> True, AxesOrigin -> {0，0}]
```

which gives me the eight ellipses because of Descarte product on three variables each which takes two values.

What I want is by using Table to generate an output where value of H , J and C start at the same time such as to get {{first value of H,first value of J,first value of C},{second value of H,second value of J,second value of C},{third value of H,third value of J,third value of C}}. In the example above, the output would be two ellipse.

There is one [similar question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/236098) which provides two methods.

One is adding `Diagonal`, but here is three variables not two variables. `Diagonal` would gives three results.

The other is using `MapThread` instead of `Table`, but `ContourPlot` is not a math function.

Thank you for any and all suggestions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to what you have:

```
H = {H1, H2};
J = {J1, J2};
Cx = {C1, C2};
exprs = Table[{x, y} . H[[i]] . {x, y} + Transpose[J[[i]]] . {x, y} + 
   Cx[[i]], {i, 1, 2}]
```

> ```
> {9.81347 - 21.3135 x + x (19.75 x - 9.09327 y) - 0.313467 y + 
>   y (-9.09327 x + 9.25 y), 
>  8.6077 - 1.80385 x + x (1.75 x - 1.29904 y) - 7.80385 y + 
>   y (-1.29904 x + 3.25 y)}
> ```

```
Show[
 ContourPlot[exprs, {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 3}
  , Axes -> True
  , AxesOrigin -> {0，0}
  , Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[5],
    Point@{p1, p2}}
  ]
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the accept. I just realized that `Show` is redundant, but let's keep it there in case another plot or something else has to be superimposed.

Comment: Thanks anyway. In fact, I have another question. How to plot this in 3D frame?

Comment: There are many types of 3D plots available. I suggest you first try out `Plot3D and `ContourPlot3D` to see if those meet your requirements. Obviously you will need to have equations suitable for 3D plotting. You can start a fresh post when you have queries. The general idea on stack sites is to restrict discussion to one question per page. Regards.